# How to copy files within directory rather than a whole directory in TCL?

Tags: tcl

Because of software upgrade files are saved to a wrong directory and existing script does not work and I need to fix it. Files are saved few folders deeper in the project file. I know I can use this command to copy directories

```
file copy -force "path_files_to_copy" "path_to_copied_into"
```

This way though it will copy the folder, the path is pointing to rather than the each individual folder and file within that folder. How do I copy everything within a specified path to a new location rather than just the parent?

EDIT

I solved it, it works although it seems to me that I am using 10x more steps than it's needed to accomplish same goal. Mainly changing "\" produced by tcl to "\" which will count it as character.

```
# Copy files from this folder
set from $take_from ;# Everything from this folder
set to $bring_to ;# To this folder

set var [glob -dir $from *;]
set wordList [regexp -inline -all -- {\S+} $var] ;# makes a list 
for { set i 0 } {$i < [ llength $var ] } { incr i } { ;# Loop through files found

    set file_path [ lindex $var $i ]    
    set count 0
    set indx  0
    set limit [string length $file_path]
    set file_path_f $file_path
    set incra 0

    while { $count < $limit } { 

        set t [string index $file_path $count]      

        if { "$t" == "\\" } {

            set temp $count
            set indx $temp              
            set ll [expr $count + $incra]
            set file_path_f [string replace $file_path_f $ll $ll "\\\\"]
            incr incra

        }

       incr count 

}

#                FILES              DESTINATION
file copy -force $file_path_f           $to

}
```

Comment: Can you explain why all those dances with the result of calling`glob` are needed? That call already returns you a list of all entries in the given directory, when called like I demonstrated in my answer. So you just need to iterate over those results and use each of them in turn. I mean, my example is *complete* (I've even tested it locally using `rlwrap tclsh` before posting).

Comment: Oh, and WTF is that `;` in the `glob` invocation? The semicolon is only needed if -- for some reason -- you want to place more than one Tcl command on the same line in your script -- in which case the adjacent command will need to be separated by a semicolon. There, you're using `[cmd arg ...]` which means "execute `cmd` with arguments `arg ...` and *substitute the value it returned* in place of the `[...]` as if that value were there originally. Have you ever opened the [Tcl tutorial](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/tcltutorial.html) (especially the 7th section there)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [`glob` command](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/glob.htm) to enumerate the entries under the source directory and copy each of them separately:

```
foreach f [glob -directory $sourceDir -nocomplain *] {
    file copy -force $f $targetDir
}
```